# Asp.net mvc change DIV content without reload and without button

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, tcp, asp.net-ajax

I'm new in Asp.net mvc. I'm trying to write two simple tcp app. First app is client(Windows forms), second one host(Asp.net mvc). In First app we can write message and send it to second one app. 
I'm receive properly message in second app and I set property message in HomeController.
I want to change div 'messageDiv' on string that is in message property every time I send it from first app and set property message.

This code below show how to make it but with button. Every time we send from first app message and then click receive button in second it change properly.

It is possible to write interval which will change that div on message property?

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<h2>Waiting for messages : </h2>


@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions()
{
    UpdateTargetId = "messageDiv",
    HttpMethod = "Post"
}))
{
   <input id="btn" type="submit" value="receive"/>
}


<div id="messageDiv"></div>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public static string message { get; set; }
    // GET: Home
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        tcpHost host = new tcpHost();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string x)
    {
        return Content(string.Format(message));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need something that automatically updates your messages div whenever you/others receive a message?

You need to achieve a [real-time communication](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) (recommended) or you could use a [setInterval method in JavaScript](https://forums.asp.net/t/2090502.aspx?Calling%20MVC%20Action%20from%20JavaCripts%20using%20setInterval) which will constantly check if there are some new messages and if there are, then it will fetch and display them in messages div (not recommended).

Comment: Exactly. Like I said before, I know how to change property message in HomeController and when we click receive button it read message property and set it into div content. Can I write interval which one will read property every 2 second and replace div content? I've done this with button and ajax, now I would like do this without button.

Comment: Sure you could but it's not efficient because there will be too many sent requests to your server and plus, there could be delay up to 2 seconds. Try this: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). I suppose you have a function that checks if there are new messages using ajax. Put that function name as the first parameter and 2000 (miliseconds, 1000 miliseconds = 1 second) as the second parameter. I think it should work without any modifications.

Comment: It works! Now I will try build this app with SignalR. Thank you very much.